# Loop variable error while using different syntax for "for loop"

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop, syntax

When i'm using `for` like 
`for i in 1 2 3 4 5`
then my file contains

`#!/bin/sh` at the top

But when i'm using `for(( i = 0; i<=5; i++))` then it is showing error

`Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`

and running properly when I remove shebang.

Please tell me the reason behind this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run with BASH, so use BASH shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Since this `arithmetic BASH loop syntax` isn't supported in `older bourne shell`:

```
for ((i = 0; i<=5; i++)); do
   echo "$i"
done
```